# Creating Bootstrap Accordion within a foreach loop

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a dynamic note field where each conversation in inclosed within a separate accordion and am having a bit of trouble.

I went ahead and copied the base code from bootstrap and noticed that the way they call the different things that need to happen. So I tried to add my unique id for each item `{{ $cover_design_note->id }}` at the end of each id to try and make it work...but that didn't seem to work. It actually seemed to break it a little more.

Any help would be wonderful, I've been struggling with this for a while.

My code looks like this

```
@foreach($cover_design->notes as $cover_design_note)
    <div class="noteAcc">
      <div class="accordion" id="accordion{{ $cover_design_note->id }}">
        <div class="accordion-group">
          <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse{{ $cover_design_note->id }}" data-parent="#accordion{{ $cover_design_note->id }}" href="#collapse{{ $cover_design_note->id }}">Collapsible Group Item #1</a>
          </div><!--.accordion-heading-->
          <div id="collapse{{ $cover_design_note->id }}" class="accordion-body collapse in">
          <div class="accordion-inner">
                              Anim pariatur cliche...
          </div><!--.accordion-inner-->
        </div><!--.accordion-body-->
      </div><!--.accordion-group-->
     </div><!--.accordion-->
   </div><!--.noteAcc-->               
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data-toggle` attribute on the link should be left alone.

```
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion{{ $cover_design_note->id }}" href="#collapse{{ $cover_design_note->id }}">Collapsible Group Item #1</a>
```